# Display percent symbol[%] in Y axis value in google chart

Tags: google-visualization

Can anyone help to get the percent `symbol[%]` in Y axis value.

I have attched png. in that in `y axis 0 t0 18` values are there I want to see it as 0% to 18%.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF6U0.png

Comment: You can add it yourself by just add the % symbol at the end of the value? example from google playground: ['2003%',  1336060,    400361,    1001582,   997974],

Comment: its not string; its float value and its dynamic it continously changes its value ,but in my case i required ['2003', 1336060%, 400361%, 1001582%, 997974%]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to format in two places: the data and the axis.  To format the data, use a NumberFormatter:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '#%'});
// format column 1 of the DataTable
formatter.format(data, 1);
```

Format the axis values, via the `vAxis.format` option:

```
vAxis: {
    format: '#%'
}
```

Comment: Not work for me. It continues work  like 1000%-10 000% when i have min 1 and max 100. This helps me -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473337/google-chart-veritcal-axis-with-percentage-sign

Comment: Dont forget that when you use Percent, values must be below 1.
ex: 47% = 0.47,   2.65% = 0.0265

Answer (score 6):

No need of the `google.visualization` line, just the next line is needed:

```
vAxis: {
    format: "#'%'"
}
```

**Explanation:**
The difference is the double quotes and simple quote. `format` property follows ICU pattern (as per [GChart specs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart)) that is used for formatting. When the simple quotes are not used, the presence of `%` multiplies x100 the value per the ICU specs. So by adding the simple quotes, the `%` is kind of escaped ([more info](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html))

Comment: Thanks for the quotes remark, it was very useful, however this will only format the y axis, not the labels