# Google Chart veritcal axis with percentage sign

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Im using google chart api to show line chart in my application, in that chart now i want to show the vertical axis values with percentage sign. for that i tried the following option

```
chart.draw(data, {vAxis: {format:'#%'} } );
```

as mentioned in

[How do you set percentage in Google Visualization Chart API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478364/how-do-you-set-percentage-in-google-visualization-chart-api)

by '**B Seven**'

when using this method, the vertical axis values got multiplied by 100. i.e instead of '12%' - im getting 1200% in vaxis!!!!

i have checked in https://developers.google.com documents also, i cant find any approach to do this.

Is there any alternate to show percentage sign in vaxis.

Comment: What is your real value: 12 or 0.12?

Comment: 12 it is. ( have to show data for 1- 100%)

Comment: FYI: value in vaxis label is populated by chart based on the data i'm providing. im not passing any value for chart axis

Comment: So the 1200% is correct. You have to divide values with 100 to get 12%

Comment: yeah 12*100=1200, thats right :-) but i want to add only percentage sign with the exising vaxis label. see im just adding the format '#%'- which should append the '%' symbol with the existing value but it is multiplying with 100 also. that is the part i donit want. i want to restrict that to add % symbol alone, is there any options?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Escaping the percentage sign in format works for me.

```
chart.draw(data, {vAxis: {format: '#\'%\''} } );
```

This shows Y axis labels with percentage sign without any data update as I expected.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but this did: `{format: '#' + "'%'"}`  It's the same idea, maybe the API changed, it's been 3.5 years since your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that there is no data type `percentage` but only `number`, `date`... Google docs describes `hAxis.format` and `vAxis.format` as:

*For number axis labels, this is a subset of the decimal formatting ICU pattern set. For instance, {format:'#,###%'} will display values "1,000%", "750%", and "50%" for values 10, 7.5, and 0.5.*

And [ICU pattern set](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#_details) states:

```
%   Prefix or suffix    Yes Multiply by 100 and show as percentage
```

So, it seems that the only option is to divide values with 100 on server or client side.